# (0xc0000005) 'Access violation': LINQ to SQL WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq-to-sql

Application compiles with no errors. Application runs but ends with no debug errors. Stepping through it, it cuts back to the designer at this line with Output showing:

```
"The program '[24680] AppName.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'."
```

Crashes on this line:

```
Dim c_InstanceDetail As t_Instance_Detail = (From InstDet In db.t_Instance_Details Where InstDet.ID = guInstance_ID Select InstDet).Single
```

In this sub:

```
Private Sub Refresh_PCA_InstanceDetail()
    Dim c_InstanceDetail As t_Instance_Detail = (From InstDet In db.t_Instance_Details Where InstDet.ID = guInstance_ID Select InstDet).Single

    Me.DataContext = c_InstanceDetail
    Me.InstanceDetailTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
End Sub
```

EDIT: Class Variables:

```
Private db As New AppDatabase_DBDataContext 'AppDatabase_DB being the name of the dbml file - AppDatabase_DB.dbml
Private InstanceDetailTypeView As BindingListCollectionView
Property guInstance_ID As Guid
```

t_Instance_Detail was created by LINQ to SQL classes and I've tried removing it and re-adding it - no change

This works (and only returns 1 record):

```
Dim c_InstanceDetail = (From InstDet In db.t_Instance_Details Where InstDet.ID = guInstance_ID Select InstDet)
```

I'm new to LINQ to SQL and WPF, so i'm assuming i'm doing something wrong or using the LINQ to SQL Classes in a why they are unintended. If someone can let me know what i'm doing wrong here, and how i should be doing this, that would be great thanks.

Comment: What is `db.t_Instance_Details`?

Comment: I've amended my original question to include the Class Variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was the possibility of not returning a record (even though it was returning 1 record at this point in time). The below fixed it:

```
Private Sub Refresh_PCA_Instance()
    Dim c_Instance As IEnumerable(Of t_Instance)
    c_Instance = (From Inst In db.t_Instances Where Inst.ID = guInstance_ID Select Inst)

    If c_Instance.Count = 1 Then
        Me.DataContext = c_Instance
        Me.InstanceDetailTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
    ElseIf c_Instance.Count > 1 Then
        Me.DataContext = c_Instance.First
        Me.InstanceDetailTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT: The more i do this, i find better/other ways:**

```
Private Sub Refresh_PCA_Instance()
    Dim c_Instance As IEnumerable(Of t_Instance)
    c_Instance = (From Inst In db.t_Instances Where Inst.ID = guInstance_ID Select Inst).First

    Me.DataContext = c_Instance
    Me.InstanceDetailTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
End Sub
```

OR

```
Private Sub Refresh_PCA_Instance()
    Dim c_Instance As IEnumerable(Of t_Instance)
    c_Instance = (From Inst In db.t_Instances Where Inst.ID = guInstance_ID Select Inst)

    Me.DataContext = c_Instance.First
    Me.InstanceDetailTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
End Sub
```